# Convergence rate of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

The following question may seem trivial, but I'm a little bit insecure to miss something.

Assume that we have a random real-valued variable $X$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ with $\mathbb{E}(\vert X \vert^p) < \infty$ for a certain $p > 2 $. Can we then infer that $$\tag{A}\frac{X}{n} \to 0 \,\,almost\,surely?$$

My idea was that $\mathbb{E}(\vert X \vert^p) < \infty$ should imply $\mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert = \infty)=0$ which should then imply (A).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't require any condition. $\frac  X n \to 0$ almost surely for any real valued  random variable $X$ simply because $\frac x n \to 0$ for every real number $x$.

Comment: Okay, could I employ the same argument for the following: Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a stationary sequence of random variables. And let $$B_n= \sum_{i=n}^{n+m} X_n,$$ which is constantly a sum of $m \in \mathbb{N}$ consecutive elements of the sequence. Shouldn't then also $B_n/n \to 0$ almost surely, due to the constant length?